# Cannot read property '-1' of undefined

Tags: javascript, oop, canvas

This is my first attempt at using classes in a Javascript project - I'm trying to implement Conway's Game of Life in HTML5 Canvas. [Here's the code.](http://jsfiddle.net/nkorth/mhMQj/) As you can see, the first generation renders fine, but there's something wrong with the `next()` function that prevents it from running any further. (I did notice that the error in question is actually being thrown at the last line of `get()`, one of the functions called by `neighbors()`, which is called by `next()`. I can't find any problems in either function, but clearly *something's* wrong!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is [that the assumption about `%` is wrong and thus] the guards in the `get/set` functions do not work as intended:

```
-1 % 42 // results in -1
```

Happy coding.

---

I would consider *removing* the guards in the `get/set` functions and using [*sentinel values*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) (or other neighbor edge-casing) for the border (e.g. the first/last row and column are never actually drawn to the screen).

This can avoid *a significant number of guard checks* -- `get/set` will be called *a whole bunch of times* each iterations (I wouldn't even have them as functions). I consider the removal of `get/set` and guards "okay" because these operations are internal to the process and closely tied to the algorithm -- they are not directly exposed and JavaScript is only so fast.

Doing a "full grid neighbor check" is `C * O(h*w)` per cycle. While it has the same complexity, a significantly smaller `C` can make the program run much quicker.

Comment: `%` is weird, I even [checked](http://google.com/search?q=-1+%25+42) that exact case before adding it. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: I like the idea of making the map edge-wrapped, but I might take the border method in the interest of speed.

Comment: @nkorth There are a lot of tricks that can be done. The complexity can be moved into `O(alive_cells)` by simulating a 2d array with `y * w + x` indexing and then only iterating over the properties of the array (the neighbor check/update math also has to be adjusted). Alternatively, a list of `[x,y]` (or flattened indices) for the alive cells can be stored. I am not sure how to get the complexity/performance much better than that, though.

Answer (score 1):

You have this loop in `next`:

```
 for(var y = 0; y < this.height; y++){
     for(var x = 0; x < this.width; x++){
         newMap[x][y] = this.get(x, y);

         //Rule 1: any live cell with fewer than two live neighbors dies
         if(this.get(x, y) == true && this.neighbors(x, y) < 2){
             newMap[x][y] = false;
         }

         //...
```

so in your first iteration, `x` and `y` are zero. Now have a look what `neighbors` is doing:

```
this.neighbors = function(x, y){
    n = 0;
    //...
    if(this.get(x-1, y-1)){n++;}
    //...
    return n;
}
```

If `x` and `y` are `0`, it tries to inspect cell `(-1,-1)`:

```
this.map[x][y] = val;
```

But your `map` has only positive integer keys.

If you want to "wrap around", increment the values in `get` in order to avoid negative values:

```
x = (x + this.width) % this.width;
y = (y + this.height) % this.height;
```

Comment: I actually intended it to go negative, so I could make the map loop at the edges with code in the `get()` and `set()` functions. However, this was related to the problem (see pst's answer)

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
x = x % this.width;
```

does not work as expected:

```
-1 % 640
```

gives

```
-1
```

Easy fix:

```
x = (x + this.width) % this.width;
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine the first cell.  Say `x` is 0 and `y` is 0.  During your processing of that cell, you're going to end up checking `this.map[-1][-1]`.  Since `this.map[-1]` is undefined, you're not going to be able to find element -1 in it, even if it did exist (which it doesn't).

You have a few options:

- Check that `x > 0` before grabbing anything to the left of that cell, and `x < this.width - 1` before grabbing anything to the right of it.  Similar story for `y` and `this.height`.
- Make sure `this.map[x - 1]` or `this.map[x + 1]` is defined before trying to access anything in it.  Same with `y +/- 1` -- if it's undefined, consider it false.
- Define `this.map[-1]` and `this.map[whatever][-1]` as false, as well as `this.map[this.width]` and `this.map[whatever][this.height]`.
- Redo your math so that `x - 1` becomes `(x + width - 1) % width`.  Same with `y - 1`.  That ought to make the map wrap around.